# Mac OS X formatted Partitions says "Permission Denied"

Tags: partitioning, mac, external-hdd

So I have a 500GB External Drive split into 4 Partitions (Which I did in Mac OS X 10.5.8) in Disk Utility which are as followed.

Mac External Drive: 155.00GB (Mac Extended)
Ubuntu External: 155.00GB (Mac Extended)
Pirate Drive: 45.00GB (Mac Extended)
PS3 Drive: 45.00GB (FAT32)

I never set permissions on any of these drives. I switched to Ubuntu and now I'm having this problem with moving my files around or deleting them..

On the FAT32 partition I can add and delete files etc... without issue. But on the other partitions when I try to move or delete anything it says I don't have proper permission to do so. I have checked the permissions in Ubuntu, however they are grey and won't allow me to change anything. I was wanting to move stuff around to free up space and install Fedora 16 on a dedicated partition on my external drive but I don't want to delete every thing on any of the partitions. Any help would be fantastic for I am loosing it thinking that everything on my external drive in "untouchable".

Comment: OSX permissions *are* different than Linux is the drive in it's entirety formatted in FAT32? or just some partitions, also OSX native HFS+ partitions are read only in Linux.

Comment: How are OSX permissions different than Linux?

Answer (score 2):

As Uri Herrera mentions, HFS+ partitions with journaling are read-only on Linux. There's a "force" parameter you could potentially use to bypass this but it's probably not a good idea.

What makes them read-only is the journaling feature, which is not implemented in the Linux driver. Fortunately, if you have your Mac handy you could disable journaling on those partitions to enable writing from Linux.

On your Mac:

1. Open Disk Utility under Applications -> Utilities
2. Select the volume to disable journaling on.
3. Choose Disable Journaling from the File menu.

For more information, see here: https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write

Also here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/hfsplus

Once you do this, you will technically be able to write files to the HFS partitions, assuming your user has permission to do so.